# How to choose upload method in GCS Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I read that GCS Storage REST api supports 3 upload methods:

- simple HTTP uploaded
- chunked upload
- resumed upload

I see that google-api-services-storage-v1 uses resumed upload approach,
but I am curious how to change this, because resume upload wastes
2 HTTP requests 1 for metadata and the second for data.

Request body of the first request is just {"name": "xxx"}.

```
    InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(
            APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, stream);

    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()                
            .setName(id.getValue());

    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = storage.objects().insert(
            bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);

    StorageObject object = insertRequest.execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that particular library exclusively uses resumable uploads. Resumable uploads are very useful for large transfers, as they can recover from error and continue the upload. This is indeed sub-optimal in some cases, such as if you wanted to upload a very large number of very small objects one at a time.

If you want to do perform simpler uploads, you might want to consider another library, such as [gcloud-java](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.2/index.html), which can perform direct uploads like so:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.defaultInstance().service();
Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
bucket.create(objectName, /*byte[] or InputStream*/, contentType);
```

That'll [use only one request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/blob/e921bbe3a44c90039574245f4a4dce5c4fdbd669/gcloud-java-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/Bucket.java#L636), although for larger uploads I recommend sticking with resumable uploads.